# Solve the second order linear ODE $y'' -3y' +4y =x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the second order linear ODE $y'' -3y' +4y =x =F(x)$

Solution to the homogenous equation: $y_h = e^{3 x/2} (C_1 \cos \frac{\sqrt{7} \, x}{2} + C_2 \sin \frac{\sqrt{7} \, x}{2})$

Solving the particular solution now,

I made an initial guess of $y_p = Ax+B$ as $F(x)$ is just a linear function

$y'_p = A$

$y''_p = 0$

Why is my initial guess wrong? Is it because the derivative of $y'_p$ will eliminate the $x$ from my guess ?

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong? $-3A+4(Ax+B)=x$ is perfectly solvable.